# browse image and crop it immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop

First to say that I can't find anywhere solution.

I need help with cropping image before saving it.

When client browse and select u few image, with this script image will be automatically show in div. Problem is that I want to crop image :

example.

image width: 1230px

image height: 670px

I want to crop width  to 670px and show that (to be 670px 670px)

I have width and height of browse image, I just want to crop and show cropped image.

**SCRIPT :**

```
<script>
        function readURL(input) {
            for($i = 0;$i < input.files.length;$i++) {
                if (input.files && input.files[$i]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var img = new Image;

                        img.onload = function() {
                            var width = img.width; // image is loaded; sizes are available
                            var height = img.height;
                        };

                        img.src = reader.result; // is the data URL because called with readAsDataURL

                        div = $(".image-upload");
                        $(".image-upload").append("<img id='image-upload' src='"+e.target.result+"' />");
                        $("#image-upload").css({
                            "width" : "300px",
                            "height" : "300px"
                        });
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[$i]);
                }
            }
        }

        $("#files").change(function(){
            $(".image-upload").empty();
            readURL(this);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: you you want to crop the same amount of pixels from the same place in each image, or should the user be able to define a crop boundry?

Comment: @dandavis thanks for the answer, server crop image, not client

Comment: you can display the image as a background-image and use CSS's crop or background-position properties to virtually crop the image.

Comment: @dandavis yes, i know that, but is there some way to do it with javascript ?

Comment: if you have somthing against css, you could use a canvas to drawImage the uploaded image with new crop boundaries.

Comment: an image within a div might be enough. And the margin/... settings can be done in js.